# What is gftp on Golem and why is it needed?

Tags: yagna

I have a few questions regarding the `gftp` implementation that Golem uses for data transfer between providers and requstors.

- Why is it needed?
- Is it using some kind of custom protocol to transfer the files or is
  it done using normal HTTPS?
- Are there any limitations? Could it be related to speed of transfer etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gftp` is a custom protocol for transferring files via Golem Network.
Here is the repo: https://github.com/golemfactory/yagna/tree/master/core/gftp

Ad1. Golem Network (`yagna`) needs it to be able to transport binary payload between Providers and Requstors.

Ad2. It has very little in common with the classic FTP protocol. It uses Golem Service Bus (aka GSB) under the hood, to transfer bytes of data between the Golem nodes. See: https://github.com/golemfactory/ya-service-bus

Ad3. Of course, there are limitations:

- it is still in Beta phase
- it is not optimised for transfer speed **yet**.
- transfers are possible just between two nodes (it is not like IPFS, BitTorrent which are replicating resource on consecutive nodes)
- ... and more which will be subject to change, so I do not want to elaborate more right now.

Comment: I believe Golem uses docker containers to run applications/jobs. Will `gftp` applied on the volume that generated output files are located or complete docker image would be fetch/transferred to the requester?

Comment: In the bachgroud Golem use https://github.com/masneyb/gftp , right?

Comment: nope, it uses https://github.com/golemfactory/yagna/tree/master/core/gftp as stated in this answer

Comment: Thanks, naming was confusing since there is gFTP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFTP exists.